# How does FIFA shortlist the final 23 players for Ballon d'OR?

Tags: football, awards, fifa

On what basis does FIFA select the 23 player shortlist for Ballon d'OR? 
Like what kind of attributes they consider

Comment: Here is a similar question with the list of journalists that help determine the finalists https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17444/how-are-the-ballon-dor-scores-determined

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really much insight into how the 23-man shortlist is generated, other than who decides. It's presumably no different than yourself and friends discussing who should be on the shortlist however.

The shortlist is decided by the FIFA committee and some experts from France Football as shown [here](http://www.fifa.com/ballon-dor/news/y=2013/m=10/news=men-shortlists-for-fifa-ballon-2013-revealed-2207371.html)

`prdp` is referring to the actual voting on players on the shortlist.

Answer (score 0):

FIFA elects a committee to decide which all players should be nominated to 23 man shortlist. Its based on their performance not a code but a guideline. Like academy award jury. I read across a report that Real Madrid President Florentino Perez will be a part of that committee for 3rd consecutive year.

p.s -Jumpingcode, i changed my answer, review this one

Comment: Next time, [edit](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/editing) your [original answer](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/5864).

Answer (score -2):

It is awarded based on votes by coaches and captains of international teams, as well as selected journalists from around the world. The players with maximum votes are shortlisted. Its just for fan fair i think. The voting closes way before the shortlists are out.

Comment: This is incorrect

Comment: Here is a question with the correct answer and the list of *journalists* that pick the winners from the finalists https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17444/how-are-the-ballon-dor-scores-determined